# Error with nest array in function

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\newcommand{\matmul}[3]{%
\foreach \i [count=\ci] in {#3}{%
\foreach \j [count=\cj] in {#2}{%
\pgfmathparse{{\i}[0]*{\j}[0]+{\i}[1]*{\j}[1]+{\i}[2]*{\j}[2]}%
\ifnum\cj=1%
\xdef\temp{\pgfmathresult}%
\else
\xdef\temp{\temp,\pgfmathresult}%
\fi
}%
\ifnum\ci=1%
\xdef#1{{\temp}}%
\else
\xdef#1{#1,{\temp}}%
\fi
}%
}
\def\rotationX{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
\matmul{\yeet}{{\rotationX}}{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}
$\yeet$
```

Here is code that multiplies matrices together.
When I try and run it with \rotationX as one of the lists of matrices it gives this error:

```
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again> 
                   {
l.86 \matmul{\yeet}{{\rotationX}}{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}

A number should have been here; I inserted `0'.
(If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
```

If it is ran with a nest array instead such as:

```
\matmul{\yeet}{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}{{4,5,6},{4,5,6}}$\yeet$
```

It's absolutely fine and returns:

```
32.0,32.0,32.0,32.0
```

FYI I am using a discord bot to do my tikz so I don't use \begin{document}
since I don't know how else to compile tikz

Answer (score 1):

I think we were discussing this. There is always a challenge to cope with different use cases. In this expanding the argument does the trick.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\newcommand{\matmul}[3]{%
\begingroup\edef\matA{#2}%
\edef\matB{#3}%
\foreach \i [count=\ci] in \matB{%
\foreach \j [count=\cj] in \matA{%
\pgfmathparse{{\i}[0]*{\j}[0]+{\i}[1]*{\j}[1]+{\i}[2]*{\j}[2]}%
\ifnum\cj=1%
\xdef\temp{\pgfmathresult}%
\else
\xdef\temp{\temp,\pgfmathresult}%
\fi
}%
\ifnum\ci=1%
\xdef#1{{\temp}}%
\else
\xdef#1{#1,{\temp}}%
\fi
}\endgroup%
}
\begin{document}
\edef\rotationX{{1,2,3},{4,5,6}}
\matmul{\yeet}{\rotationX}{{1,2,3},{1,2,3}}
$\yeet$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm sorry the only thing I noticed you change is the fact that \matmul{\rotationX} now only has 1 pair of curly braces around it. I couldn't see any other differences and I tried \matmul with only 1 pair of curly braces and it still didnt work it just returned the same thing

Comment: @OllyEatough Does my code work or not? As I wrote, I expanded the argument, `\edef\matA{#2}%
\edef\matB{#3}%`, so I fail to understan the statement " the only thing I noticed you change is the fact that \matmul{\rotationX} now only has 1 pair of curly braces around it".

Comment: I tried your code and it did not work. I only noticed one change in your code compared to my original. That is what I was saying

Comment: @OllyEatough So you are suggesting that when I ran my above code I got error messages and just invented the output? It is not my fault if you do not post complete examples, and if you do not copy others peoples codes.